# Split android apps apk to smaller parts

Tags: android, jar, apk, android-library

I wonder how to split app in to smaller parts, that could be updated separately. Parts should contain functions and GUI. Something like dlls in Windows application development.

Main reason is to minimize data/file transfer to update app for client. And client devices can be rooted, if this leads to better solution...

Main challenge I see in splitting:

- res
- libs

Comment: You already answered yourself: the key word is **libraries**.

Comment: @DerGolem the libraries are considered a compile time artifacts. After building app it still produces one apk. I would like more parts, that can be updated individually.

Comment: You can use concept of plugins but first, mind telling **what you need this split for**?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski When apk is split, I could update just the parts, that need to be updated in case bugs or functionality expansion. Main reason is to minimise data/file transfer to client. I'll update question...

Comment: Do you distribute your apps yourself or you use Google Play? And how big is your app?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski App are used by our self. I do not think Google Play supports splitting apk and updating just individual part.

Comment: It may be that the apps updates will be served as deltas by Google Play shortly this is already happening with Chrome. and if so, and your app is distributed via Google Play, then no point bothering.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thanks for pointing this out, but I am looking for solution\advices now and for non-google-play distribution

Comment: See my answer. Rest is on you

Comment: @Solata: not entirely. you can depend on external libraries that are already installed on the device. see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, but I do not find any sample how to use this without including any jar files or linking directly to Android Library Project. As I replied recently, this is also considered a compile time artifact and it produces single apk. Please post this as an answer and add some sample or url link.

Comment: @Solata: this method allows you to indicate that your apk was compiled linked to that library, but the library does not have to be packaged in the apk. It means you can distribute the apk and the library independently. However I have used that only on custom AOSP, and I don't know how it can be usable for third-party libraries

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to split your app into smaller apps (you can make these smaller apps "invisible" in Launcher with easy so no problem for use). Main app need then to communicate with these "slaves" to have certain tasks done. You can do that with regular `startActivityForResult()`, or you can try to [communicate using AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html). This require all the "slaves" to be already installed prior calling (you can check that with PackageManager). Additionally, depending on what you really need that for you can have your "slaves" downloadable on demand, using [DexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did't know about DexClassLoader. Will test this shortly. App is developed for industry where every byte counts, so it is not a waste of time.